# cannot convert parameter 1 from 'char' to 'LPCWSTR'

Tags: c++, windows, createfile, lpcwstr

I keep getting this error:
`cannot convert parameter 1 from 'char' to 'LPCWSTR'`

```
int main(int argc, char argv[])    
{

   // open port for I/O
   HANDLE h = CreateFile(argv[1],GENERIC_READ|GENERIC_WRITE,0,NULL,OPEN_EXISTING,0,NULL);

   if(h == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
       PrintError("E012_Failed to open port");
```

can someone help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should be

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
```

And

```
HANDLE h = CreateFileA(argv[1],GENERIC_READ|GENERIC_WRITE,0,NULL,OPEN_EXISTING,0,NULL);
```

Comment: I don't thing using the ANSI version of CreateFile is the right way to go, next thing you know and he'll start changing all the function calls to use the ANSI version.

Comment: @Nikola: Of course it's the wrong way! I just think that it's not appropriate to explain the difference between char, wchat_t, TCHAR and how to write correct unicode applications to an absolute beginner.

Answer (score 127):

Go to the Properties for your Project and under Configuration Properties/General, change the Character Set to "Not Set". This way, the compiler will not assume that you want Unicode characters, which are selected by default:

[image]

Comment: Scouring around for hours till I found this thanks

Comment: Now under Configuration Properties / Advanced.

Answer (score 5):

This is the main function that Visual Studio creates by default:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
```

Where _TCHAR is defined to be char or wchar_t depending if _UNICODE is defined or not. The same thing happens with API functions. I would advise you against using explicit CreateFileA. Change your main and use CreateFile.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your compiler setting for *CharacterSet*, you may need to perform a multibyte / widechar conversion, or change the CharacterSet if you don't care what it is.

For converting with MultiByteToWideChar, see the following...

http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=231165

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're compiling with Unicode enabled. Then with `char argv[]`, `argv` is a `char` array, so `argv[1]` is a `char`, and `CreateFile` wants a `const wchar_t*` as first parameter, not a `char`.

That said, your `main` definition is also broken, it should have `char* argv[]`. With that change, you can call `CreateFileA`.